# Problema con GIT al subir por primera vez al remoto

Tags: git, github

Cree un repositorio en github para subir un proyecto academico que estoy realizando. 
Instale el *gitbash* para trabajar en windows con la consola de comandos, configure las variables globales de **user.name user.email**.

Ejecute las siguientes sentencias

```
git add 
git commit - m"primer commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/cristian16b/SICU.git
```

El problema sucede cuando `git push` porque me genera el siguiente error que se muestra en la captura de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pueden orientar o darme alguna recomendación sera bienvenida. Estoy dando mis primeros pasos con git.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no soy un experto con github pero me pasó algo parecido a lo que dice tu error **integrate the remote changes (e.g 'git pull'...) before pushing again**

prueba hacer un `git pull` de tu repositorio remoto,
puede que si has añadido ó modificado un archivo  desde github y no desde tu pc, tienes que traerte esos cambios a tu local y mezclarlos con tu repositorio

hay 2 maneras de traer los cambios de tu repo en github y luego mezclarlos con tu repo local.

la primera es con `git fetch [origin] [master]` origin es tu repo remoto y master es la rama master
**OJO** no pongas los corchetes [], solo pon lo que está dentro, si tienes otros nombres para el remoto y la rama, pues eso lo sabras tu. Ésto es para traerte los cambios... y luego para mezclarlos usas `git merge`

la **2da manera** es más fácil ya que trae y mezcla de una vez y es con `git pull [origin] [master]`

luego de traerte y mezclar los cambios solo debes hacer lo tipico de `git add .` , `git commit -m "mensaje"` y por ultimo el `git push [origin] [master]`

bueno, espero eso resuelva tu error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la info, me fue util para solucionar el problema. Aprovecho a copiar un hilo [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255655/trying-to-pull-files-from-my-github-repository-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-his] que tambien puede serles utiles si se les presenta el error **fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories**.